# Is there a tool to produce annotated source code for Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am just starting out with trying to comprehend a very large Haskell project. Because most type annotations are left out, I am having difficulty following the code simply by reading it.

I was wondering if there is any tool that would produce [annotated source code](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/example/ExampleValidation.scala.html). This would be like [Scala X-Ray (aka Browse)](https://github.com/harrah/browse), but for Haskell.